# Persons without emotions

Tags: identification-request, yoga-vashishtha

In Yoga Vasista, I remember a story whose summary is given below

> A powerful Rakshasa creates two persons, who have no emotions at all.
> Devas find it hard to defeat both of them. Then they ask brahma for an
> idea to defeat them. Brahma told Devas to do acts that increase
> emotions in both people. Devas did accordingly and as a result the two
> persons got emotion and later defeated by Devas.

What are the names of two persons? Are they human or some other species?